# zero standard error when estimating parameters with mle2

Tags: r

I am estimating with mle2, and I keep getting 0 standard errors for all of my parameters (also when the fit is bad). Can anyone tell me why?  Is there a smarter way to estimate with maximum likelihood?

```
# Define Log likelihood function for product i.  
LL<-function(product, gamma0, beta_0, beta_1,  beta_2, beta_3, beta_4, beta_5, beta_6, beta_7, beta_8, beta_9,beta0, beta1, beta2, beta3, beta4, beta5, beta6, beta7, beta8, beta9, var1) {

          y <- data_$Patients_ln[data_$Brand==product]
          R <- myfunc(product, gamma0, beta_0, beta_1,  beta_2, beta_3, beta_4, beta_5, beta_6, beta_7, beta_8, beta_9,beta0, beta1,beta2, beta3, beta4, beta5, beta6, beta7,beta8, beta9)

          R <- - sum(dnorm(y,mean=R, sd=exp(var1), log=TRUE)) 

          return(R)
        }

        # Sum all the log likelihood function ( sum over all products)
        sumLL <- function(gamma0, beta_0, beta_1, beta_2, beta_3, beta_4, beta_5, beta_6, beta_7, beta_8, beta_9
                          , beta0, beta1, beta2,beta3, beta4, beta5, beta6, beta7, beta8, beta9, var1) {

          products <- unique(data_$Brand)


          sum_ <- 0


          for(i in 1:length(products)){
            sum_ <- sum_ +  LL(products[i], gamma0, beta_0, beta_1, beta_2, beta_3, beta_4, beta_5, beta_6, beta_7, beta_8, beta_9, beta0, beta1, beta2,beta3, beta4, beta5, beta6, beta7, beta8, beta9, var1)
          }

          return(sum_)
        }

 fit<- mle2(sumLL, start=list(gamma0=values[1], beta_0=values[2],beta_1=values[3],beta_2=values[4],beta_3=values[5],beta_4=values[6],beta_5=values[7],beta_6=values[8],beta_7=values[9],beta_8=values[10],beta_9=values[11],  beta0=values[12], beta1=values[13], beta2=values[14],beta3=values[15], beta4=values[16], beta5=values[17],beta6=values[18],beta7=values[19], beta8=values[20], beta9=values[21], var1=values[22]), control=list(maxit=3000))
```

This is my output:

[image: code output]

Comment: Hi Amanda. I'm not sure what you mean. None of your standard errors are zero. Can you explain what you are expecting to see?

Comment: Many of the standard errors are on the order of 1E-15, which is within the machine precision of zero.

Comment: I might be a statistical question better answered on cross validated https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is this a matter of overfitting? How many observations do you have?

Comment: @mob You have to divide 1e-15 by another ~1e300 to get near zero in R.  The question is really concerned with the model fit and the right eyeballs for it are over on Cross Validated.

Comment: @Maurits:  I  have around 657 observations and 9 products, but I dont know if the code might take the n=9 products as the number of observations.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers.

@Allan: I would expect the standard errors to be greater than 1E-15 since the fit is not very good.

@I have tried to remove the parameters and only estimate the model with 1-2 parameters, but the standard errors are still almost 0.

Best, 
Amanda